# PySCIPOpt/SCIP - isLPSolBasic() not in pyscipopt.scip.Model

Tags: python, discrete-mathematics, scip

I developed a gomory cut for a LP problem (based on 'test-gomory.py' test file) which I could not manage to run. Finally, I copied the test file to check whether I'd the same trouble. Indeed I got the same message:

*if not scip.isLPSolBasic():
AttributeError: 'pyscipopt.scip.Model' object has no attribute 'isLPSolBasic'*

I have downloaded SCIPOptSuite 5.0.1 win64, set up path and installed pyscipiopt using pip on conda. 
I cannot figure what is wrong, except that I may have failed to install pyscipopt properly? Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct: The pip version of PySCIPOpt was outdated and did not yet include the latest updates with respect to cutting plane separators. I just triggered a new release build (v.1.4.6) that should be available soon.

When in doubt, you can always build PySCIPOpt from source by running `python setup.py install` from within the project directory.

Comment: Great, I fell relieved somehow...
I'd suggest to edit the INSTALL.rst file in gitHub to advise on installation options using Windows with and without Anaconda.